# Slant on background image with opacity

Tags: css, svg, background, opacity

I am making a One-Page webstie to practise Flexbox etc.

To do that, Im using PSD file and I have some troubles. 
I wanna make rectangle with an oblique upper side with opacity on my background, i read about svg and should I do it with that like on this picture:

[(brown thing with opacity throughout the website view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq6eR.jpg)

I have again similar problem. I have a pic: [image]

And it should looks like:[image]

Tips will be great

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.viget.com/articles/angled-edges-with-css-masks-and-transforms/) it might help you, then you'll only need to give your div a transparence with either `opacity` or using the alpha channel of an `rgba(0,0,0,0.4)` background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach without gradient.

**Create a wrapper**
It can be the div with background image. Important thing is you need to `overflow: hidden` and `position: relative`.

**Create a rectangle and rotate it**
You can create a `:before` pseudo element like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  opacity: .5;
  bottom: -100px;
  left: -100px;
  right: -100px;
  height: 150px;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with a CSS gradient.

Here I have a `<div>` with two backgrounds:

1. the image
2. a CSS linear gradient on top of it.

The sharp edge of the gradient works because there are two gradient steps that coincide. Meaning the gradient colour jumps straight from transparent to 50% blue.

I've used blue so that it shows up well in this example.  In your case, just switch it to brown.

```css
div {
  width: 1240px;
  height: 648px;
  background: linear-gradient(175deg, rgba(0,0,200,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,200,0) 70%, rgba(0,0,200,0.5) 70%, rgba(0,0,200,0.5) 100%),
              url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq6eR.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```